# Can't Install Apache2 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, installation, apache2

I get this error whenever i try to install apache2 or reinstall it.

I tried to delete all its packages already and did an autoremove but that didn't work.

> sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2

> sudo apt-get autoremove

I deleted apache2.data also.

I made sure there is no folder of apache2 left on my computer from previous installations.

> whereis apache2

and i removed all folders.

Then i tried to install it again :

> sudo apt-get install apache2

Comment: Don't post images. No one can read any of that.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/256013/177579

Comment: Here are the reasons why you [shouldn't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some service is already running on port 80 and hence you're getting that error. You may need to change your apache2 port to something else.
For this, open `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Then change `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost *:8080>`.
Then run:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

And change `Listen 80` to `Listen 8080`.
And now, run:

```
sudo systemctl start apache2
```

This should start apache2 server on `localhost:8080`.